# Process Builder and Flows

Tags: process-builder, lookup, visual-flows

I have a custom field which has a lookup to contact. How do i extract the Id of the lookup and pass it on in a flow using a process builder ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable in your flow as input only. Lets say `AccountId`. In your process builder when you select action as `Execute Flow` and choose the invokable flow with no screens elements, this variable will be available in your process builder to assign and you can assign this value using a reference value type.

[image: Process Image]